# Differential equation $x+f(x)f'(x)+f'(x)f''(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $x+f(x)f'(x)+f'(x)f''(x)=0$

My working:

By integrating **WRT** $x$ we get $ x^2+ f(x)^2+f'(x)^2=c^2 $ for some $c\ge 0$

Now $x\in [-c,c]$

let us consider OPS for $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$

$\implies x^2+(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots)^2+(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\cdots)^2=c^2$

$\implies a_0^2+a_1^2=c^2,1+a_1^2+2a_0a_2+4a_2^2+6a_1a_3=0$ etc.

Comment: @HenryLee: I fail to see why replacing “w.r.t.” by ”**WRT**” is necessary, or improves the question.

Comment: Indeed it is the grossest edit I have ever seen here.

Comment: I'm sorry you do not like it, feel free to revert the change